# How to increase maximum file open limit (ulimit) in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ulimit

Currently `ulimit -n` shows `10000`. I want to increase it to `40000`. I've edited `/etc/sysctl.conf` and put `fs.file-max=40000`. I've also edited `/etc/security/limits.conf` and updated hard and soft values. But still ulimit shows `10000`. After making all these changes I rebooted my laptop. I've access to root password.

```
usr_name@usr_name-lap:/etc$ /sbin/sysctl fs.file-max
fs.file-max = 500000
```

Added following lines in `/etc/security/limits.conf` -

```
*     soft    nofile          40000
*     hard    nofile          40000
```

I also added following line in `/etc/pam.d/su`-

```
session    required   pam_limits.so
```

I've tried every possible way as given on other forums, but I can reach up to a maximum limit of `10000`, not beyond that. What can be the issue?

I'm making this change because neo4j throws maximum open file limits reached error.

Comment: Remove the change to `sysctl.conf` and reboot! You don't want to set the *system-wide* file descriptor limit to 40,000! (Check `/etc/security/limits.d`, the problem is most likely there.)

Comment: or you can as sudo use `root` instead of `*`. You actually want both. Then log-out, back in and you are butter.

Comment: take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21515463/how-to-increase-maximum-file-open-limit-ulimit-in-ubuntu